# LOAD BLOB COLUMN INSTEAD OF FILE

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database

Is there a way to load data from blob column instead of file like

```sql
LOAD DATA FROM (SELECT A.B FROM A) INTO TABLE TEMP FIELDS
TERMINATED BY ' ' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

instead of load data infile ?

Answer (score 0):

Too late for the OP but it may be useful to someone else in the future.

Assuming a table `my_blobs` like:

| id | blob_data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "row1 col1" "row1 col2" "row 1 col3" "row 2 col1" "row 2 col2" "row 2 col3" ... |
| 2 | ... |
| 3 | ... |

The simplified version is to export all the space separated data from the table into a single file and then import it.

```sql
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM blob_data) FROM my_blobs
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file.txt'
FIELDS ESCAPED BY '';

LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file.txt'
INTO TABLE `TEMP`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

If the data in your blobs has header rows, then the headers will get imported multiple times, but they can be removed after the import.

A more convoluted (but flexible) approach is to dump the contents of the column using [`SELECT ... INTO DUMPFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html) and then read the file back in to the target table using [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).

You could use a query like this to write the dump/load script:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
    'SELECT blob_data FROM my_blobs WHERE id = ', id,' INTO DUMPFILE \'/path/to/csv_export_', id,'.csv\';\n',
    'LOAD DATA INFILE \'/path/to/csv_export_', id,'.csv\'\nINTO TABLE `TEMP`\nFIELDS TERMINATED BY \' \' ENCLOSED BY \'"\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\';\n\n'
) FROM my_blobs
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/process_csv_files.sql'
FIELDS ESCAPED BY '' ENCLOSED BY '';
```

Which will create the file `/path/to/process_csv_files.sql` with content like:

```sql
SELECT blob_data FROM my_blobs WHERE id = 1 INTO DUMPFILE '/path/to/csv_export_1.csv';
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/csv_export_1.csv'
INTO TABLE `TEMP`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';


SELECT blob_data FROM my_blobs WHERE id = 2 INTO DUMPFILE '/path/to/csv_export_2.csv';
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/csv_export_2.csv'
INTO TABLE `TEMP`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';


SELECT blob_data FROM my_blobs WHERE id = 3 INTO DUMPFILE '/path/to/csv_export_3.csv';
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/csv_export_3.csv'
INTO TABLE `TEMP`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Obviously, `/path/to/` needs to be readable and writable by the mysqld process. This may be restricted by the [`secure_file_priv`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv).

Note ([from MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html#:%7E:text=A%20given%20SELECT%20statement%20can%20contain%20at%20most%20one%20INTO%20clause%2C%20although%20as%20shown%20by%20the%20SELECT%20syntax%20description%20(see%20Section%C2%A013.2.13%2C%20%E2%80%9CSELECT%20Statement%E2%80%9D)%2C%20the%20INTO%20can%20appear%20in%20different%20positions)):

> A given `SELECT` statement can contain at most one `INTO` clause, although as shown by the `SELECT` syntax description (see [Section 13.2.13, “SELECT Statement”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)), the `INTO` can appear in different positions:
>
> - Before `FROM`. Example:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT * INTO @myvar FROM t1;
>   ```
> - Before a trailing locking clause. Example:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT * FROM t1 INTO @myvar FOR UPDATE;
>   ```
> - At the end of the `SELECT`. Example:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT * FROM t1 FOR UPDATE INTO @myvar;
>   ```
>
> The `INTO` position at the end of the statement is supported as of MySQL 8.0.20, and is the preferred position. The position before a locking clause is deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.20; expect support for it to be removed in a future version of MySQL. In other words, `INTO` after `FROM` but not at the end of the `SELECT` produces a warning.